# Looping through in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have written following function in JS which is called on click of some element in Client Side.I want to loop thru in jQuery,but following code is not working.

```
function HideShowMenu( pStart, pLength)

$(document).ready(function(){

    for ( i=pStart ; i <= pLength ; i++ ) {

        $('#tr_menu_'+i).show();
     } 

});

// return   
return;  
}
```

How can i go about it?

Comment: Why do you have `$(document).ready...` *inside* the function? How are you binding the event handler? How is the handler called?

Comment: am forced to think that it shud be `$(document).ready(function(){/*the function and actual code here*/});` instead of what Romit has written

Comment: oops, inside out dude, put your doc ready function on the outside brov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `$(document).ready();`. Correct way is something like this:

```
function HideShowMenu( pStart, pLength){
    for (var i=pStart ; i <= pLength ; i++ ) {
        $('#tr_menu_'+i).show();
    } 
}   

$(document).ready(function(){
    HideShowMenu(1,10);
});
```

`$(document).ready()` should be outside any other function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    HideShowMenu(0, 5);
});
function HideShowMenu(pStart, pLength) {
    for ( var i=pStart; i <= pLength; i++ ) {
        $('#tr_menu_' + i).show();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').each(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function HideShowMenu() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tr_menu_').each(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
}
```